# BASH: Padding a series of HEX values based on the longest string

Tags: bash, awk

I have this odd condition where I've been given a series of HEX values that represent binary data.  The interesting thing is that they are occasionally different lengths, such as:

```
40000001AA
0000000100
A0000001
000001
20000001B0
40040001B0
```

I would like to append 0's on the end to make them all the same length based on the longest entry.  So, in the example above I have four entires that are 10 characters long, terminated by '\n', and a few short ones (in the actual data, I 200k of entries with about 1k short ones).  What I would like to do figure out the longest string in the file, and then go through and pad the short ones; however, I haven't been able to figure it out.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, if you append 0's to your data, you're changing the values. You might want to consider _prepending_ the 0's.

Comment: @MatthewBurke yeah, due to a quirk, they data is an inverse, so the end is actually the beginning.  <shrug>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general to zero-pad a string from either or both sides is (using `5` as the desired field width for example):

```
$ echo '17' | awk '{printf "%0*s\n", 5, $0}'
00017

$ echo '17' | awk '{printf "%s%0*s\n", $0, 5-length(), ""}'
17000

$ echo '17' | awk '{w=int((5+length())/2); printf "%0*s%0*s\n", w, $0, 5-w, ""}'
01700

$ echo '17' | awk '{w=int((5+length()+1)/2); printf "%0*s%0*s\n", w, $0, 5-w, ""}'
00170
```

so for your example:

```
$ awk '{cur=length()} NR==FNR{max=(cur>max?cur:max);next} {printf "%s%0*s\n", $0, max-cur, ""}' file file
40000001AA
0000000100
A000000100
0000010000
20000001B0
40040001B0
```

Comment: This is worked really well.  I'm on a BSD system, so most other solutions didn't work as they were GNU specific.

Answer (score 3):

Using standard two-pass awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if (len < length()) len=length(); next}
     {s = sprintf("%-*s", len, $0); gsub(/ /, "0", s); print s}' file file

40000001AA
0000000100
A000000100
0000010000
20000001B0
40040001B0
```

Or using gnu `wc` with `awk`:

```
awk -v len="$(wc -L < file)" '
   {s = sprintf("%-*s", len, $0); gsub(/ /, "0", s); print s}' file

40000001AA
0000000100
A000000100
0000010000
20000001B0
40040001B0
```

Answer (score 2):

As you use `Bash` there is a big chance that you also use other `GNU`
tools. In such case `wc` can easily tell you the the length of the
greatest line in the file using `-L` option. Example:

```
$ wc -L /tmp/HEX
10 /tmp/HEX
```

Padding can be done like this:

```
$ while read i; do echo $(echo "$i"0000000000 | head -c 10); done < /tmp/HEX
40000001AA
0000000100
A000000100
0000010000
20000001B0
40040001B0
```

A one-liner:

```
while read i; do eval printf "$i%.s0" {1..$(wc -L /tmp/HEX | cut -d ' ' -f1)} | head -c $(wc -L /tmp/HEX | cut -d ' ' -f1); echo; done < /tmp/HEX
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have this values in file:

```
file=/tmp/hex.txt
```

Find out length of longest number:

```
longest=$(wc -L < $file)
```

Now for each number in file justify it with zeroes

```
while read number; do
    printf "%-${longest}s\n" $number | sed 's/ /0/g'
done < $file
```

This what will print script to stdout:

```
40000001AA
0000000100
A000000100
0000010000
20000001B0
40040001B0
```

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some, but not all, of the issues with this answer. Just use awk. for clarity, efficiency, robustness, portability and most other desirable attributes of software.